# docker-composeでnginxからstaticフォルダーが参照できるnginx-app.confの設定

Tags: nginx, docker, django, docker-compose

お世話になっております
docker-compose初心者です
不透明な点、不足点等あればご指摘お願いいたします

参考にした記事
https://sleepless-se.net/2018/06/12/dockerdjango

利用したリポジトリ
https://gitlab.com/sleepless-se/django-uwsgi-nginx-https

環境
CentOS Linux release 7.5.1804 (Core) 
Django==2.1.2
djangorestframework==3.9.0
docker==3.5.1
docker-compose==1.23.0

私は今、docker-composeを使ってDjangoをHTTPS化してデプロイしようと試みています
参考にした記事のリポジトリを利用してWebアプリのHTTPS化は成功しました
しかし、Nginxからstaticフォルダーが参照できておらず、CSS等が適用できていない状態です

記事を見るとnginx-app.confを設定するようですが、自分の環境での書き方がわからず悩んでいます

Djangoのアプリはappの中にプロジェクトの中身を全て入れてあります
appのディレクトリの場所は以下の通りです
/home/centos/django-uwsgi-nginx-https/django-uwsgi-nginx/app

現在以下のようにappの直下にstaticフォルダがある状態です
app
├── db.sqlite3
├── manage.py
├── project
├── requirements.txt
├── static
├── templates

記事では以下のようにnginx-app.confを設定するとあります

location /static {
        alias /code/app/プロジェクト名/static;
}

ですが私のstaticフォルダはapp直下のため、以下のように書いたのですが機能しませんでした

location /static {
        alias /code/app/static;
}

docker-compose.ymlは以下の通りです(ドメインは記載を変えています)

```html
version: '3'
services:
  https-portal:
    image: steveltn/https-portal:1
    ports:
      - '80:80'
      - '443:443'
    environment:
      DOMAINS: 'example.com -> http://django:8080'
      STAGE: 'production' #'local'
    # volumes:
    #   - /data/ssl_certs:/var/lib/https-portal

  django:
    build: ./django-uwsgi-nginx
    volumes:
    - ./django-uwsgi-nginx/app:/code/app
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
```

nginxからstaticフォルダーが参照できるには書き方が違うのか
それとも他になにか原因が考えられるのか
わかる方いらっしゃいましたらよろしくお願いします

Comment: `/home/centos/django-uwsgi-nginx-https/django-uwsgi-nginx/app` これはDockerコンテナ内のパスがこうなっているのでしょうか？ `nginx-app.conf`にはDockerコンテナ内のパスを書く必要があり、元の記事から特に`docker-compose.yml`をいじっていないのであれば`/code/app/django-uwsgi-nginx/app/static`となるはずです。

Comment: コメントありがとうございます、docker-compose.ymlの内容を追加しました、教えていただいた通りに設定したのですがやはりstaticフォルダは参照できていないです

Comment: 追記いただきありがとうございます、ちょっと間違えたようです。おそらく正しい答えを回答にしました。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`docker-compose.yml`について、`volumes`の設定が`#`でコメントアウトされているのはわざとでしょうか？　このコメントアウトを外さないとアプリが動作しないと思います。参考にした記事のほうではコメントアウトが外されています。

```
#volumes:
#- ./django-uwsgi-nginx/app:/code/app
```

nginxの設定ですが、以下のようにすれば動くのではないかと思います。

```
location /static {
    alias /code/app/static;
}
```

---

以降は解説です。Dockerコンテナ内で動くアプリは、外部から隔離されたファイルシステムが見えています。ですから、コンテナの外（ホスト側）に存在するファイルは何らかの方法でコンテナの内側から見えるようにしてあげる必要があります。

その方法の一つが`volumes`の設定で、質問文にある`docker-compose.yml`の設定は外側の`./django-uwsgi-nginx/app`がコンテナ内での`/code/app`に対応するようにしてくださいという意味になります。

そして、nginxの設定ですが、nginxはコンテナ内で動作しているため、コンテナ内のファイルシステム上のパスを教えてあげる必要があります。質問文にある`/home/centos/django-uwsgi-nginx-https/django-uwsgi-nginx/app/static`というのはおそらくホスト側のパスでしょうから、これはコンテナ内のnginxには見えません。

今回、`./django-uwsgi-nginx/app`（これは`/home/centos/django-uwsgi-nginx-https/django-uwsgi-nginx/app`のことですよね）がコンテナ内での`/code/app`に対応するように設定しました。ということは、`/home/centos/django-uwsgi-nginx-https/django-uwsgi-nginx/app/static`は`/code/app/static`に対応するはずです。ですから、上述のように`/code/app/static`をnginxに設定してあげることでnginxからstaticディレクトリが参照できるようになると思います。

Comment: ご丁寧に解説までいただきありがとうございます、コメントアウトはミスでした。しかしご指摘の通りコメントアウトを外し、/code/app/staticを指定したのですがstaticフォルダが参照されませんでした

Comment: こちらで試してみたところ、`/code/app/static`を指定することでstaticフォルダを参照させることができました。残る可能性としては、`nginx-app.conf`の変更が反映されていないことが考えられます。設定を変更した場合、Dockerイメージを再ビルドしないと反映されません。　`docker-compose up`ではなく`docker-compose up --build`としてアプリを起動してみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: ありがとうございます、再ビルドはしているのですがやはりstaticフォルダは参照されませんでした。ログを見ると**152 static files copied to '/code/app/static'.**と出ているのでstaticフォルダはきちんと認識しているように思います。**python3 manage.py runserver**では動作するので大丈夫だと思っていたのですがDjango側で設定がおかしいのかもしれません

Comment: 現在の設定だと、例えば`app/static/style.css` を読み込むためのURLは `https://example.com/static/style.css` になりますが、やりたいことはこれで間違っていないでしょうか？　（もちろんドメインは自分の物に読み替えていただくとして）

Comment: その通りです。いまsetting.pyを見て修正したところ解決しました。どうやらSTATIC_ROOTでデプロイ環境のためにcollectstaticが静的ファイルを集めるディレクトリが設定されていなかったのが問題だったようです。

Answer (score 1):

今回はnginx-app.confのstaticフォルダの指定を間違えていた点もそうですが
STATIC_ROOTを設定していなかったため、virtualenvのテスト環境では動作しても
dockerのデプロイ環境では動かないという初歩的ミスがありました

デプロイ環境のためにはSTATIC_ROOTにcollectstaticが静的ファイルを集めるディレクトリの指定が必要だと理解していなかったのが原因です

ただDjangoの管理ページのCSSが適用していないのでまた原因を探る必要があります
拙い文章で分かりづらかったと思うのですが、丁寧に解説までしてくださり本当にありがとうございました